# Unable to Add new User For AZURE Windows VM Using VMAccessAgent

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-for-java

I am trying to add a new username and password after creating a Windows virtual machine from the existing snapshot. I am using the java SDK sample code available on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/b8933cc5c3581361579bd2956f837421b003d0a8/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager-samples/src/main/java/com/azure/resourcemanager/compute/samples/ManageVirtualMachineExtension.java#:%7E:text=using%20VMAccess%20extension-,windowsVM.update(),.apply()%3B,-System.out) but this code snippet only updates the existing user's password instead of creating a new user.

Here is my code snippet

```
virtualMachine.update().defineNewExtension("VMAccessAgent")
.withPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
.withType("VMAccessAgent")
.withVersion("2.3")
.withProtectedSetting("username", user)
.withProtectedSetting("password", plainTextPassword)
.attach().apply();
```

Comment: Have you tried using  `windowsVMAccessExtensionVersionName = "2.4"` ? References: [az vm user update using VMAccessAgent version 2.0 instead of 2.4](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11626), [Upgrade VMAccessAgent version. The VM was restarted by running az vm user update](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12633) and [VMAccessAgent 2.4 for Windows operating system](https://www.edureka.co/community/94058/how-to-update-a-user-account-in-azure)

Comment: Yeah @DeepDave-MT i tried with 2.4 version but still facing the same issue

Comment: Alternatively, you can try with Azure CLI: [az vm user update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-update)

Comment: [Unable to Add new User For AZURE Windows VM Using VMAccessAgent](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/29261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried multiple ways and finally found the solution seems like it is case sensitive
instead of **withProtectedSetting** use **withPublicSetting** for username and the change the key to **UserName** and **Password**
and change the version to 2.4

```
    virtualMachine.update().defineNewExtension("VMAccessAgent")
        .withPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
        .withType("VMAccessAgent")
        .withVersion("2.4")
        .withPublicSetting("UserName", user)
        .withProtectedSetting("Password", palinTextPassword)
        .attach().apply();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).